# Controller action is not available

Tags: laravel, laravel-routing

I am not familiar with laravel but from what I red I made this:
My controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class ChatController extends Controller
{
    public function index(Request $request)
    {
        var_dump(123123);die;
        if (!Auth::check()) {
            return redirect('/');
        }

        return 1;
    }
}
```

Now I am trying to request it like `domain.com/open-chat`. And my `web.php` configuration about it is:

```
Route::get('/open-chat', 'ChatController@index');
```

But I am getting redirected to the home page. I`ve checked the middleware controllers if some of it redirects me but no. The other controllers ( which were already made when I came ) works fine. What am I missing ?

**EDIT**
web.php

```
<?php

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
|
*/

Route::get('/clear-cache', function() {
    Artisan::call('cache:clear');
    return "Cache is cleared";
});
Route::get('/config-cache', function() {
    Artisan::call('config:cache');
    return "Config is cleared";
});

Route::get('/view', function() {
    Artisan::call('view:clear');
    return "View is cleared";
});

/* Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
}); */

Route::group(['prefix' => 'siteadmin', 'namespace' => 'Admin'], function () {

    Route::get('/', 'Auth\LoginController@showLoginForm');
    Route::post('login', 'Auth\LoginController@login')->name('admin.login');
    Route::post('logout', 'Auth\LoginController@logout')->name('admin.logout');
});

Route::group(['prefix'=>'siteadmin', 'namespace' => 'Admin','middleware' => 'auth'], function () {  
    Route::get('/dashboard', 'DashboardController@index')->name('dashboard.index');
    Route::get('/edit-profile', 'CommonController@editProfile');
    Route::post('/updateprofile', 'CommonController@updateprofile');

    /**
        Routes for site settings
    **/
    Route::get('/site-settings', 'SiteSettingController@index')->name('sitesettings.index');
    Route::post('/site-settings/store', 'SiteSettingController@store')->name('sitesettings.save');


    Route::get('/subject-categories', 'SubjectCategoriesController@index')->name('subject-categories.index');
    Route::get('/subject-categories/create', 'SubjectCategoriesController@create')->name('subject-categories.create');
    Route::post('/subject-categories/store', 'SubjectCategoriesController@store')->name('subject-categories.store');
    Route::get('/subject-categories/edit/{id}', 'SubjectCategoriesController@edit')->name('subject-categories.edit');
    Route::post('/subject-categories/update/{id}', 'SubjectCategoriesController@update')->name('subject-categories.update');
    Route::get('/subject-categories/drop/{id}', 'SubjectCategoriesController@drop')->name('subject-categories.drop');
    Route::post('/subject-categories/delete-image/{id}', 'SubjectCategoriesController@deleteImage');


    /**
        Routes for teachers users
    **/
    Route::get('/users/teachers', ['middleware'=>'auth','uses'=>'UserController@getTeachersList'])->name('teachers.index');
    Route::get('/users/teachers/create', ['middleware'=>'auth','uses'=>'UserController@createTeacher'])->name('teachers.create');
    Route::post('/users/teachers/save', ['middleware'=>'auth','uses'=>'UserController@saveTeacher'])->name('teachers.save');
    Route::get('/users/teachers/edit/{id}', ['middleware'=>'auth','uses'=>'UserController@editTeacher'])->name('teachers.edit');
    Route::get('/users/teachers/show/{id}', ['middleware'=>'auth','uses'=>'UserController@showTeacher'])->name('teachers.show');
    Route::post('/users/teachers/update/{id}', ['middleware'=>'auth','uses'=>'UserController@updateTeacher'])->name('teachers.update');
    Route::get('/users/teachers/delete/{id}', ['middleware'=>'auth','uses'=>'UserController@deleteTeacher']);
    Route::get('/users/teachers/change-status/{id}', ['middleware'=>'auth','uses'=>'UserController@changeTeacherStatus']);
    Route::post('/users/get-cities-by-country', ['middleware'=>'auth','uses'=>'UserController@getCitiesByCountry']);
    Route::get('/users/teachers/messages/{id}', ['middleware'=>'auth','uses'=>'UserController@getTeacherMessageThreads'])->name('teachers.messages');
    Route::get('/users/teachers/view-message/{id}', ['middleware'=>'auth','uses'=>'UserController@getAllMessagesByThreadID'])->name('teacher.view-message');
    Route::post('/users/teachers/delete-profile-image/{id}', ['middleware'=>'auth','uses'=>'UserController@deleteTeacherProfileImage']);

    /**
        Routes for driver users
    **/
    Route::get('/users/students', ['middleware'=>'auth','uses'=>'UserController@getStudentsList'])->name('students.index');
    Route::get('/users/students/create', ['middleware'=>'auth','uses'=>'UserController@createStudent'])->name('students.create');
    Route::post('/users/students/save', ['middleware'=>'auth','uses'=>'UserController@saveStudent'])->name('students.save');
    Route::get('/users/students/edit/{id}', ['middleware'=>'auth','uses'=>'UserController@editStudent'])->name('students.edit');
    Route::get('/users/students/show/{id}', ['middleware'=>'auth','uses'=>'UserController@showStudent'])->name('students.show');
    Route::post('/users/students/update/{id}', ['middleware'=>'auth','uses'=>'UserController@updateStudent'])->name('students.update');
    Route::get('/users/students/delete/{id}', ['middleware'=>'auth','uses'=>'UserController@deleteStudent']);
    Route::get('/users/students/change-status/{id}', ['middleware'=>'auth','uses'=>'UserController@changeStudentStatus']);

    /**
        Routes for countries
    **/
    Route::get('/countries', ['middleware'=>'auth','uses'=>'CountryController@index'])->name('countries.index');
    Route::get('/countries/create', ['middleware'=>'auth','uses'=>'CountryController@create'])->name('countries.create');
    Route::post('/countries/save', ['middleware'=>'auth','uses'=>'CountryController@store'])->name('countries.save');
    Route::get('/countries/edit/{id}', ['middleware'=>'auth','uses'=>'CountryController@edit'])->name('countries.edit');
    Route::get('/countries/show/{id}', ['middleware'=>'auth','uses'=>'CountryController@show'])->name('countries.show');
    Route::post('/countries/update/{id}', ['middleware'=>'auth','uses'=>'CountryController@update'])->name('countries.update');
    Route::get('/countries/delete/{id}', ['middleware'=>'auth','uses'=>'CountryController@destroy']);
    Route::get('/countries/change-status/{id}', ['middleware'=>'auth','uses'=>'CountryController@changeStatus']);
    Route::post('/countries/delete-image/{id}', ['middleware'=>'auth','uses'=>'CountryController@deleteImage']);

    /**
        Routes for cities
    **/
    Route::get('/cities', ['middleware'=>'auth','uses'=>'CityController@index'])->name('cities.index');
    Route::get('/cities/create', ['middleware'=>'auth','uses'=>'CityController@create'])->name('cities.create');
    Route::post('/cities/save', ['middleware'=>'auth','uses'=>'CityController@store'])->name('cities.save');
    Route::get('/cities/edit/{id}', ['middleware'=>'auth','uses'=>'CityController@edit'])->name('cities.edit');
    Route::get('/cities/show/{id}', ['middleware'=>'auth','uses'=>'CityController@show'])->name('cities.show');
    Route::post('/cities/update/{id}', ['middleware'=>'auth','uses'=>'CityController@update'])->name('cities.update');
    Route::get('/cities/delete/{id}', ['middleware'=>'auth','uses'=>'CityController@destroy']);
    Route::get('/cities/change-status/{id}', ['middleware'=>'auth','uses'=>'CityController@changeStatus']);
    Route::post('/cities/delete-image/{id}', ['middleware'=>'auth','uses'=>'CityController@deleteImage']);

    /**
        Routes for subjects
    **/
    Route::get('/subjects', ['middleware'=>'auth','uses'=>'SubjectController@index'])->name('subjects.index');
    Route::get('/subjects/create', ['middleware'=>'auth','uses'=>'SubjectController@create'])->name('subjects.create');
    Route::post('/subjects/save', ['middleware'=>'auth','uses'=>'SubjectController@store'])->name('subjects.save');
    Route::get('/subjects/edit/{id}', ['middleware'=>'auth','uses'=>'SubjectController@edit'])->name('subjects.edit');
    Route::get('/subjects/show/{id}', ['middleware'=>'auth','uses'=>'SubjectController@show'])->name('subjects.show');
    Route::post('/subjects/update/{id}', ['middleware'=>'auth','uses'=>'SubjectController@update'])->name('subjects.update');
    Route::get('/subjects/delete/{id}', ['middleware'=>'auth','uses'=>'SubjectController@destroy']);
    Route::get('/subjects/change-status/{id}', ['middleware'=>'auth','uses'=>'SubjectController@changeStatus']);

    /**
        Routes for classes
    **/
    Route::get('/classes', ['middleware'=>'auth','uses'=>'ClassController@index'])->name('classes.index');
    Route::get('/classes/create', ['middleware'=>'auth','uses'=>'ClassController@create'])->name('classes.create');
    Route::post('/classes/save', ['middleware'=>'auth','uses'=>'ClassController@store'])->name('classes.save');
    Route::get('/classes/edit/{id}', ['middleware'=>'auth','uses'=>'ClassController@edit'])->name('classes.edit');
    Route::get('/classes/show/{id}', ['middleware'=>'auth','uses'=>'ClassController@show'])->name('classes.show');
    Route::post('/classes/update/{id}', ['middleware'=>'auth','uses'=>'ClassController@update'])->name('classes.update');
    Route::get('/classes/delete/{id}', ['middleware'=>'auth','uses'=>'ClassController@destroy']);
    Route::get('/classes/change-status/{id}', ['middleware'=>'auth','uses'=>'ClassController@changeStatus']);
    Route::post('/classes/get-subjects-by-category', ['middleware'=>'auth','uses'=>'ClassController@getSubjectsByCategory']);

    /**
        Routes for sliders
    **/

    Route::get('/sliders', 'SliderController@index')->name('sliders.index');
    Route::get('/sliders/create', 'SliderController@create')->name('sliders.create');
    Route::post('/sliders/store', 'SliderController@store')->name('sliders.save');
    Route::get('/sliders/edit/{id}', 'SliderController@edit')->name('sliders.edit');
    Route::post('/sliders/update/{id}', 'SliderController@update')->name('sliders.update');
    Route::get('/sliders/delete/{id}', 'SliderController@destroy')->name('sliders.delete');
    Route::get('/sliders/change-status/{id}', ['middleware'=>'auth','uses'=>'SliderController@changeStatus']);
    Route::post('/sliders/delete-image/{id}', 'SliderController@deleteImage');


    /**
        Routes for teacher classes
    **/

    Route::get('/teacher-classes', 'TeacherClassController@index')->name('teacher-classes.index');
    Route::get('/teacher-classes/create', 'TeacherClassController@create')->name('teacher-classes.create');
    Route::post('/teacher-classes/store', 'TeacherClassController@store')->name('teacher-classes.save');
    Route::get('/teacher-classes/edit/{id}', 'TeacherClassController@edit')->name('teacher-classes.edit');
    Route::post('/teacher-classes/update/{id}', 'TeacherClassController@update')->name('teacher-classes.update');
    Route::get('/teacher-classes/delete/{id}', 'TeacherClassController@destroy')->name('teacher-classes.delete');
    Route::post('/teacher-classes/get-subjects-by-category', 'TeacherClassController@getSubjectsByCategory');
    Route::post('/teacher-classes/get-classes-by-category-and-subject', 'TeacherClassController@getClassesBySubjectAndCategory');

    /**
        Routes for orders
    **/

    Route::get('/orders', 'OrderController@index')->name('orders.index');
    Route::get('/orders/show/{id}', 'OrderController@show')->name('orders.show');
    Route::get('/orders/export-orders', 'OrderController@exportOrders')->name('orders.export-orders');

    /**
        Routes for bookings
    **/

    Route::get('/bookings', 'BookingController@index')->name('bookings.index');
    Route::get('/bookings/teacher-bookings/{teacher_id}', 'BookingController@getTeacherAllBookings')->name('bookings.bookings');
    Route::get('/bookings/show/{id}', 'BookingController@show')->name('bookings.show');
    Route::get('/bookings/export-teacher-bookings/{teacher_id}', 'BookingController@exportTeacherBookings')->name('bookings.export-teacher-bookings');

    /**
        Routes for bookings
    **/

    Route::get('/messages', 'MessageController@index')->name('messages.index');
    Route::get('/messages/show/{id}', 'MessageController@show')->name('messages.show');

    /**
        Routes for reviews
    **/

    Route::get('/reviews', 'ReviewController@index')->name('reviews.index');
    Route::get('/reviews/show/{id}', 'ReviewController@show')->name('reviews.show');


    /**
        Routes for blogs
    **/

    Route::get('/blogs', 'BlogController@index')->name('blogs.index');
    Route::get('/blogs/create', 'BlogController@create')->name('blogs.create');
    Route::post('/blogs/store', 'BlogController@store')->name('blogs.save');
    Route::get('/blogs/edit/{id}', 'BlogController@edit')->name('blogs.edit');
    Route::post('/blogs/update/{id}', 'BlogController@update')->name('blogs.update');
    Route::get('/blogs/delete/{id}', 'BlogController@destroy')->name('blogs.delete');
    Route::get('/blogs/change-status/{id}', ['middleware'=>'auth','uses'=>'BlogController@changeStatus']);
    Route::post('/blogs/delete-image/{id}', 'BlogController@deleteImage');

});

Auth::routes();

Route::get('{locale?}', 'HomeController@index');
Route::get('/en', 'HomeController@index');
Route::get('/open-chat', 'ChatController@index');
Route::get('/ar', 'HomeController@index');
Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');

Route::post('/get-cities-by-country', 'SearchController@getCitiesByCountry');
Route::post('/get-subjects-by-category', 'SearchController@getSubjectsByCategory');

Route::post('/register', 'CommonController@register');
Route::post('/login', 'CommonController@login');
Route::post('/forgot-password', 'CommonController@forgotPassword');
Route::get('/{locale?}/reset-password/{token}', 'CommonController@resetPassword');
Route::post('/{locale?}/resetpassword', 'CommonController@resetNewPassword')->name('reset-pass');

Route::get('/{locale?}/classes/search', 'ClassController@searchClasses')->name('search');
Route::get('/{locale?}/classes/all-cities', 'ClassController@getAllCitiesClasses');
Route::get('/{locale?}/classes/{type}/{id}', 'ClassController@getClassesByType');

Route::get('/{locale?}/view-class/{id}', 'ClassController@viewTeacherClassDetails')->name('view-class');
Route::get('/{locale?}/finish-class/{id}', 'ClassController@finishTeacherClass')->name('finish-class');

Route::post('/create-booking', 'CommonController@createBooking');
Route::post('/{locale?}/submit-review', 'CommonController@submitReview');

Route::get('/{locale?}/blogs', 'HomeController@getAllBlogs')->name('blogs');
Route::get('/{locale?}/blogs/{slug}', 'HomeController@getBlogDetails')->name('blogs.detail');


Route::get('/paypal/checkout/{order}/completed', [
    'name' => 'PayPal Express Checkout',
    'as' => 'paypal.checkout.completed',
    'uses' => 'User\BookingController@completed',
]);

Route::get('/paypal/checkout/{order}/cancelled', [
    'name' => 'PayPal Express Checkout',
    'as' => 'paypal.checkout.cancelled',
    'uses' => 'User\BookingController@cancelled',
]);

Route::post('/webhook/paypal/{order?}/{env?}', [
    'name' => 'PayPal Express IPN',
    'as' => 'webhook.paypal.ipn',
    'uses' => 'User\BookingController@webhook',
]);

/**
    User dashboard routes start
**/
Route::group(['prefix'=>'{locale?}/user', 'namespace' => 'User','middleware' => 'auth'], function () {
    Route::get('/dashboard', 'DashboardController@index')->name('user.dashboard');
    Route::get('/edit-profile', ['uses'=>'ProfileController@editProfile'])->name('user.edit-profile');
    Route::post('/update-profile/{id}', ['uses'=>'ProfileController@updateProfile'])->name('user.update-profile');
    Route::post('/update-image/{id}', ['uses'=>'ProfileController@updateUserImage'])->name('user.update-image');
    Route::get('/change-password', ['uses'=>'ProfileController@changePassword'])->name('user.change-password');
    Route::post('/update-password', ['uses'=>'ProfileController@updatePassword'])->name('user.update-password');

    Route::get('/my-classes', ['uses'=>'ClassController@getTeacherClasses'])->name('user.my-classes');
    Route::get('/my-classes/add-new-class', ['uses'=>'ClassController@createNewClass'])->name('user.add-new-class');
    Route::post('/my-classes/save-class', ['uses'=>'ClassController@saveClass'])->name('user.save-class');
    Route::get('/my-classes/edit-class/{id}', ['uses'=>'ClassController@editClass'])->name('user.edit-class');
    Route::post('/my-classes/update-class/{id}', ['uses'=>'ClassController@updateClass'])->name('user.update-class');
    Route::get('/my-classes/delete-class/{id}', ['uses'=>'ClassController@deleteClass']);


    Route::post('/get-subjects-by-category', ['uses'=>'ClassController@getSubjectsByCategory']);
    Route::post('/get-classes-by-category-and-subject', ['uses'=>'ClassController@getClassesByCategoryAndSubject']);

    Route::get('/my-bookings', ['uses'=>'BookingController@getAllBookings'])->name('user.my-bookings');
    Route::get('/my-bookings/view-booking-details/{id}', ['uses'=>'BookingController@viewBookingDetails'])->name('user.view-booking-details');
    Route::get('/my-bookings/cancel-booking/{type}/{id}', ['uses'=>'BookingController@cancelBooking']);
    Route::get('/my-bookings/accept-booking/{id}', ['uses'=>'BookingController@acceptBooking']);
    Route::post('/make-a-payment', ['uses'=>'BookingController@makePayment'])->name('user.make-payment');

    Route::get('/my-orders', ['uses'=>'OrderController@getAllOrders'])->name('user.my-orders');
    Route::get('/messages', ['uses'=>'MessageController@getMessageThreads'])->name('user.messages');
    Route::get('/messages/view-messages/{thread_id}', ['uses'=>'MessageController@getAllMessagesByThreadID'])->name('user.view-messages');
    Route::post('/messages/send-message', ['uses'=>'MessageController@sendMessage']);

    Route::get('/reviews', ['uses'=>'BookingController@getAllReviews'])->name('user.reviews');

});
```

Extended `Controller.php`:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

    use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\DispatchesJobs;
    use Illuminate\Routing\Controller as BaseController;
    use Illuminate\Foundation\Validation\ValidatesRequests;
    use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\Access\AuthorizesRequests;

    class Controller extends BaseController
    {
        use AuthorizesRequests, DispatchesJobs, ValidatesRequests;
    }
```

Comment: Check `php artisan route:list` if your route is not overwriting or being overwritten. I cant see an issue what the code you posted. Perhaps the extended  `Controller` has some extra logic.

Comment: problem is related to this line `Route::get('{locale?}', 'HomeController@index');` if you comment this line, it'll work. but why? I don't have any idea!!. if you move `Route::get('/open-chat', 'ChatController@index');` above that line I think I'll work. temporary solution

Comment: @Mojtaba Sayari Indeed that fixed it :/ . I`ll post the extend controller as well now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This rule `Route::get('{locale?}', 'HomeController@index');` is catching all routes because it's always true. so Laravel follows this route.

the problem is not about `Route::get('/open-chat', 'ChatController@index');` if you put any route after that one, it won't work.

we usually use this to catch all request to forward somewhere like Vuejs router or show 404 message.

```
Route::any('{catchall}', 'CatchAllController@handle')->where('catchall', '.*');
```

and these are pretty same. if you put `Route::get('{locale?}', 'HomeController@index');` at the end of your router file, everything should work fine.

Answer (score -2):

It's normal, var_dump doest stop the script and `die` should be `die()`. Instead, use `dd(123123)`. Everything is fine with the controller.

Since the route doesn't have the auth middleware, we can assume that the route is open to everyone. In the controller, you are checking if the use is authenticated, if not, redirect to `/`.

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken `die;` should still stop the execution.

Comment: @Rwd , no, you are not mistaken.